# Xcode 4.2 hangs on "Attaching to (AppName)" until second run

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I'm having this issue when I hit Run on the simulator/device, the project compiles successfully but all I see is "Attaching to (AppName)". If I run the project again, it's working fine.

Same is happening when running on the device, but I get alert message, "Could not read from device".

Any ideas?

Comment: Restart Xcode... If it doesn't work, reboot. If it still doesn't work, reboot your iPhone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same issue for weeks on our project. We finally resolved it by removing some of the build warnings we had, specifically ones like:

> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/yosit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogobot-dnimbqlmegonbvcyvulfebiqqeor/Build/Products/DebugProduction-iphonesimulator/Gogobot.app/UAPushLocalization.bundle

This happens when you have the same resource filename in different folders on the same project. In our case we removed the UI folder for Urban Airship since we didn't need it. It brought down the number of warnings and removed the problem completely.